# Negative values in DEM after mosaic?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, erdas-imagine

I downloaded 2 1/3 arcsecond DEMs from the national map as .img files. First I ran the Mosaic to New Raster tool in Arcmap. The values of the first DEM are 49.0551 to 1111.13. The values for the second DEM are 274.089 to 3505.05. The output is -78.4316 to 3505.05. I have tried changing some of the options as follows.

Pixel type: 32bit float, 32 bit unsigned (this one gave a low of 0)

Mosaic Operator: All the possible options

So then I tried it in ERDAS with mosaic express. I got the same result.

I looked at the histograms, not just the stretch classification to confirm the values.

I used the pseudocolor option in ERDAS to locatate the negatave pixels of which there are many thousands. They are not located at the seam line, rather it is a big valley that is the lowest area of the DEM.

---

I downloaded the DEM again, but this time as arcgrid. Now it displays the min of -78 instead of 49 and the max is now 1875 instead of 1111. Not sure why the IMG gave different values. I went to google earth to check if this is an error. Turns out that at the very edge of the DEM it does drop below sea level, so it is correct. I still do not understand why the IMG file did not display the -78 and 1875 in the first place. I would not have been worried if the min and max of the mosaic output was the same as the inputs.

Comment: Overkill. Set extent to mosaic. Use raster calculator to compute A. The same for B. Raster calculator Con(isnull(A), B,A)

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand.

Comment: Where in the US are these DEMs placed? Have you tried looking at the result with the negative values? are they perhaps edge pixels?

Comment: Are the negative pixels within the overlap area of the two DEM? Are there nodata values in the area? If yes, the nodata values could be recognized as DEM values and used by the resampling process producing negative values

Comment: The negative values are not at the seam line or edges. That would have made sense and not really be a concern to me. The negative pixels fill a low valley in the terrain and the area is very large with thousands of pixels.

Comment: I also tried doing it again in Arcmap. This time I set the processing extent to the intersection of the rasters and that also did not help.

Comment: FYI - If you want people to see your responses you need to ping them with @username.

Comment: Again the question, are there any nodata pixels in the low valley area in one (or both) of the input DEM? I suppose, that the nodata values are ignored in the statistics of the Input DEM, but are not recognized as nodata values by the resampling process.

Comment: @GeographyNerd Please add all additional information as an [edit] to your question, not in comments